# Appropriate regeneration of StrepTrap HP columns for FPLC

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, purification, chromatography

My question is related to protein purification using a ÄKTA FPLC.
We used StrepTrap HP Columns (1 ml column Volume (CV)) from GE Healthcare Life Sciences to purify a strep-tagged protein. In the first approach, this worked pretty fine.
We wanted to re-use the columns after regenerating them according to the official protocol. The included steps were all performed at a flow rate of 1 ml/min and with filtered solutions:

1. 3 CV distilled water
2. 3 CV 0.5 M NaOH
3. 3 CV distilled water
4. 5 CV 20 % EtOH
5. Storage of columns in 20 % EtOH at 4°C.
6. Equilibration of the columns with Binding Buffer just before next use.

By adhering to the protocol we encountered some problems with the next purification (it was the same protein, but a new sample of cell extract). The purification worked less effective and the amount of purified protein was very low.

We tried a slightly different protocol for regeneration, also at a flow rate of 1 ml/min and filtered solutions.

1. 5 CV distilled water
2. 5 CV 20 % EtOH
3. 3 CV 6 M Guanidinhydrochloride (*sol.*)
4. 5 CV 0.5 M NaOH
5. 3 CV distilled water
6. 5 CV 20 % EtOH
7. Storage in 20 % EtOH at 4°C
8. Equilibration with Binding Buffer before next use.

We chose the Guanidinhydrochloride to denaturate all remaining proteins from the column resin and support the regeneration by this.
But also with this protocol we encountered the same problems (low efficiency of purification).

I would be very interested if anyone of you have encountered the same problems and maybe have a solution/better protocol for this regeneration step.

Thank you for your suggests in advance! :)

Comment: What was the exact problem with the second purification (eg poor binding, poor elution, etc). Did anything change with the preparation of the second sample? Did you use desthiobiotin for the first elution? Is there a lot of biotin in the culture medium?

Comment: We used desthiobiotin (2.5 mM in Binding Buffer (Tris, NaCl, EDTA)) as Elution buffer. The second sample was prepared exactly the same way as the one before (same incubation time, same induction of protein expression). Additionaly we tried it with another protein (with a new column) and observed the same problem. Meaning: First purification was rather good, the second was not so nice. The culture medium contained 0.2 g/l Biotin (CGXII+Glucose). What we observed during the FPLC was, that the peak for the eluted protein was not very high. We are not sure, if this is because of poor binding.

Comment: Or because of poor elution. We tested the flowthrough on an SDS-PAGE and it seems in both cases (the first attempt, where the purification was fine, and the one where it was not) that we have enough protein in the sample (strong bands at the expected MW of our protein in the cell extract and still in the flowthrough.).

Comment: How much of your target protein is in the flow through compared to the sample that was applied? That should tell you how well it is binding. You might want to think about how much of the biotin in the culture medium is making it to your column. Biotin will bind with very high affinity and prevent binding of the strep-tagged protein. It might be irrelevant but is perhaps worth considering.

Comment: Is there a technique to determine the amount of target protein in the cell extract and in the flow through? I guess a BCA Assay e.g. would just give you the amount of total protein in the sample? The remaining Biotin is a very good point I have not thought about at this point! Is a HABA assay an appropriate way to measure the Biotin amount in the sample?

Comment: I would just compare the bands on SDS-PAGE. You don’t really need to determine the exact amount that bound but rather just get a rough idea of whether it is binding at all.

Comment: HABA binds to streptavidin in the same site where biotin binds, so you could use it in combination with streptavidin to assay biotin concentration. That might be more trouble than it’s worth though. If you are worried about biotin blocking the column, you could instead use HABA to check the column for binding capacity.

Comment: You might try contacting customer support before you get too deep into troubleshooting yourself as they may have seen a lot of these problems and have solutions already.

Comment: Ah okay, we did this already. What you can observe is, that you have a rather strong band for the cell extract and also for the flow through (we chose a very high induction rate, which is tolerated by the organism). And also for the fraction, where the purified protein should be, you can see a very clear and strong band. We approved, that the protein is in all three samples by Western blotting, where you can see a very nice and clear signal for the purified fraction. This is only for the first attempt with a fresh column, the second run resulted in a much lower signal for the pur. protein.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. The first approach before overextending the tests would be to ask customer support. I was just curious for some ideas or experiences with this problems. I will add it here, if there might be some useful input from the customer support! Thank you very much for your assumptions and ideas :)

Comment: There could be a couple of things affecting the binding capacity of the column, but prime suspects would be either damage to the strep-tactin proteins or some sort of irreversible binding occurring. I would contact support and give them all details of your experiment.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect we are having issues with the column regeneration too. Did customer support ever get back to you? I've not worked with StrepTraps before, but I'd expect the resin to last more than half a dozen purifications, so I'm working with we haven't managed to elute all the protein from previous runs and all the column is saturated meaning all new proteins flow straight through. It would be great if you could share how you fixed this! Thanks
Abbie